Laravel React login form axios post getting 419 CSRF token mismatch error when SESSION_DRIVER set to 'database' instead of 'file' in session.php
So I've managed to get my login form working in React hooked up to Laravel server side by initially setting 'support_credentials' to true in cors.php, having the SESSION_DRIVER set to 'file', and then in my react Login.jsx file containing the form submission handler: doing a get request for the sanctum cookie and then post request passing in the retrieved cookie X-XSRF-TOKEN in the header, all this can be seen in the code below and works fine. I now wish to switch the SESSION_DRIVER from 'file' to 'database' as this is required for the project but as a result now get the following 419 'csrf token mismatch' error. Been struggling how to solve this. Any help would be much appreciate please, thank you.
CRSF token mismatch console error when trying to log in
Laravel 'cors.php' file 
Laravel 'session.php' file
Laravel 'env.php' file
React Login.jsx submit handler for login process, axios user here is imported from custom 'axios' config file created, showed in other image
React custom axios.js config file

Ensure that you have a database table to contain the session data. Docs. And confirm if your SESSION_DOMAIN is correct. Because in axios you are using localhost:8000, but SESSION_DOMAIN is just localhost.

Okay just managed to solve what the issue was. Turned out my colleague had modified the original sessions table to have additional columns which had constraints to other tables and for some reason this caused the whole muck up issue with the crsf token mismatch, beacuse when session_driver is set to database that record is inserted to the default laravel 'sessions' table upon any server side post/get request made to laravel which was what was happening as soon as I hit log-in. To solve I simply dropped the current sessions table I had, overwrote it with the default Laravel sessions table.
